# Is it a good idea to cache data in a mobile application when reading a NoSQL DB?

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-cloud-firestore

I'm really new in Xamarin.

It's been some weeks I've started an app to play with, and I've just discovered NoSql world with Firebase DB stuff.

I read/watch a lot of things, it was a big jump from the Relational DB world !

I'm asking for some advices about this topic please : **caching or not caching data in a mobile app when data is coming from a NoSQL DB.**

*Examples of data to cache :*

- Authenticated user main informations,
- Authenticated user favorite items,
- ...

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to cache data in a mobile application when reading a NoSQL DB?

Yes, it is since it makes your app work even if the device goes offline.

> caching or not caching data in a mobile app when data is coming from a NoSQL DB.

Absolutely yes. According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline):

> You can write, read, listen to, and query the cached data. When the device comes back online, Cloud Firestore synchronizes any local changes made by your app to the Cloud Firestore backend.

Besides that:

> - For Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default.
> - For the web, offline persistence is disabled by default. To enable persistence, call the enablePersistence method. Cloud Firestore's cache isn't automatically cleared between sessions.

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't yet thinking about offline devices. I've originally thought about performances and saving network data.

Answer (score 1):

You should surely cache your data for a user session, while the user is still using the application.
You can allow the user to do pull to refresh.
Best with firebase DB you can have events published and update your cache accordingly.